# Creating a sum based on a category within a date range

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, sumifs

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet that I can easily take an export from Mint.com's CSV outputs and get them into my Excel budget.

To do so, I need a way to populate each field within a date range. I'd like to avoid macros if possible (I don't know how to make them).

I'm happy to share my finished .xls with the public!

I've imported Mint.com's data in a manner that has column S for the date (3/30), column V with the cash value that I need to add up, and column X for the spending category. 
I need to tally each month's spending ($V) by category (column X).

Through research, I devised this (for my January "Gas & Fuel" spending):

> =SUMIFS($W$2:$W$900, $T$2:$T$900, ">="&W$12, $T$2:$T$900, "<"&(EOMONTH(D$1,0)+1), $Y$2:$Y$900, "="&$B5)

However, it required that I reformat my Dates, which is an issue because this would become specific to each year and I would need to change the fields every year. I'd like the document to be usable without adjustment using my spending data from the past and future.

Is there a way to take the year out of the equation? To make that formula above work, I renamed my column from "January" to "1/14".

[Here is what the spreadsheet looks like](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hcj42x8ekzd4doh/Screenshot%202014-04-02%2000.19.32.png)

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of split do you want?

Comment: thanks for your reply, through revision, I believe have clarified my question.

Answer (score 1):

A pivot table would work best with that data.

Initial set up would show each day separately, but by using Grouping
[image]
*(here) **^^^***
you can group the data by month/day/year/however